# Working way to access Consul agent from a Vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, consul

I have a Win2012R2 virtual machine running in VirtualBox 5 using a Vagrant provisioning.

In the VM I run a single Consul 0.8.0 agent (I'm not interested in clustering at the moment) with the following command line:

```
consul.exe agent -server -dev -client=0.0.0.0 -bind=0.0.0.0
```

This launches Consul with the following attributes:

```
Server: true (bootstrap: false)
Client Addr: 0.0.0.0 (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600)
Cluster Addr: 10.0.2.15 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
Gossip encrypt: false, RPC-TLS: false, TLS-Incoming: false
Atlas: <disabled>
```

So now I need to access this Consul agent, especially the REST api for putting and getting KV data, from the Host machine (Linux).

In order to do this, in the vagrantfile I configure the following port-forwarding:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8500, host: 8900
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 5000
```

The port 80 is for exposing a WebApplication API that we deploy together in the VM, and which by the way is supposed to use Consul as configuration engine.

Accessing the application **from the linux Host** at address `http://localhost:5000` works fine. However, if i try to read any Consul key at address `http://localhost:8900/v1/kv/mykey`, e.g. with `curl`, the session will be hanged indefinitely.

I guess it's worth remarking that both the webapplication API and the Consul APIs can be accessed from within the VM guest without problems.

I suspect the problem with Consul may lie with the need to expose / forward more ports from the Guest to the Host, like for example the port 8600? However I tried some experiments without success and at the moment I am blocked by this.

Or maybe the reason is the `consul.exe` command line launch, where I have to add more attributes?

What am I missing? Any idea how to make Consul agent accessible from the external world?

thanks!

Comment: did you try to start the VM with a static IP ? use this IP for the consul command ... can you reach consul keys if you're within the VM?

Comment: I tried to configure -client=<vm-ip> -bind=<vm-ip> in the command line to launch consul.exe, but nothing changes.

Comment: From within the VM: the application can be reached at `localhost:80`, Consul can be reached at `localhost:8500`. From the host OS: the application can be reached at `localhost:5000`, Consul CANNOT be reached at `localhost:8900`.